# Looking to find duplicate emails but with having a different name in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Hello I am trying to find what customer have the same emails but having a different name. Pretty much what happen is in our name, first name, last name it populate the email name so it looks like janedoe-at-yahoo. So was able to find all the -at- now I want to match those emails with the correct name Jane Doe so I can fix all the -at- emails. Hope that all made sense please help.

```
SELECT C.CUST_NO, C.NAM, C.EMAIL_ADRS_1
FROM AR_CUST C
  INNER JOIN (SELECT NAM, EMAIL_ADRS_1, COUNT(*) AS COUNTOF
                         FROM AR_CUST
                         GROUP BY NAM, EMAIL_ADRS_1
                         HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
                        ) DT ON C.NAM = DT.NAM AND C.EMAIL_ADRS_1 =   DT.EMAIL_ADRS_1 
ORDER BY C.EMAIL_ADRS_1
```

This code will bring up all the duplicate emails only

```
SELECT C.CUST_NO, C.NAM, C.FST_NAM, C.LST_NAM, C.EMAIL_ADRS_1
FROM AR_CUST C
  INNER JOIN (SELECT NAM, EMAIL_ADRS_1, COUNT(*) AS COUNTOF
                         FROM AR_CUST
                         GROUP BY NAM, EMAIL_ADRS_1
                         HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND NAM LIKE '%-at-%'
                        ) DT ON C.EMAIL_ADRS_1 = DT.EMAIL_ADRS_1 
ORDER BY C.EMAIL_ADRS_1
```

This code will bring me the -at- emails and some of the correlate names but it only brings me 100 records when there should be at least 900 records

Comment: Sample data and expected result, please.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello I am trying to find what customer have the same emails but having a different name.

If you just wand the email address that are duplicates, you can answer this with aggregation:

```
SELECT C.EMAIL_ADRS_1
FROM AR_CUST C
GROUP BY C.EMAIL_ADRS_1
HAVING MIN(C.NAM) <> MAX(C.NAM);
```

If you want the original records, use `exists`:

```
select c.*
from ar_cust c
where exists (select 1
              from ar_cust c2
              where c2.email_adrs_1 = c.email_adrs_1 and
                    c2.nam <> c.nam
             );
```